# Is there a MySQL versioning and migration which supports users, or only users?

Tags: mysql, migration

Is there a way to Declaratively manage your Users and permissions in MySQL >= 5.7?  I would like to specify my structure and have it generate the necessary SQL to alter it to that state.

As far as I can tell, to manage MySQL Users and their permissions the commercial tools are all Graphical Interfaces ([Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), [dbForge](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/)) which do not provide automation interfaces (ex. Executing DDL from a bash script)

Neither [Prisma](https://github.com/prisma/prisma), [Loopback](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback), or [SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy) provide user permissions in their migrations (To do that with each connector would be impossible)

Is there any tool with which I can take a serialized format (ex. permissions.json) with a database connection, and receive the SQL necessary for the Server's User state(users, permissions, hosts, passwords) to match the serialized format?

Comment: On what OS shall that tool run? What is your price margin?